# Calling async method without awaiting blocks execution of the rest of ASP.NET Core services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm currently working on ASP.NET Core WebApp, which consist of web server and two long-running services– **TCP Server** (for managing my own clients) and **TCP Client** (integration with external platform).

Both of services are running alongside web sever– I achieved that, by making them inherit from **BackgroundService** and injecting to DI in this way:

```
services.AddHostedService(provider => provider.GetService<TcpClientService>());
services.AddHostedService(provider => provider.GetService<TcpServerService>());
```

Unfortunately, while development I ran into weird issue (which doesn't let me sleep at night so at this point I beg for your help). For some reason async code in TcpClientService blocks execution of other services (web server and tcp server).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ClientService.AsyncPoblem
{
    public class TcpClientService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TcpClientService> _logger;
        private bool Connected { get; set; }
        private TcpClient TcpClient { get; set; }

        public TcpClientService(ILogger<TcpClientService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Connected)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100, stoppingToken); // check every 100ms if still connected
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 1234);
                        HandleClient(TcpClient); // <-- Call causing the issue
                        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "After call");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // log the exception, wait for 3s and try again
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, "An error occured while trying to connect with server.");
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, e.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(3000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            Connected = true;

            await using var ns = client.GetStream();
            using var streamReader = new StreamReader(ns);

            var msgBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            bool reading = false;
            var buffer = new char[1024];
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var res = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

                foreach (var value in buffer)
                {
                    if (value == '\x02')
                    {
                        msgBuilder.Clear();
                        reading = true;
                    }

                    else if (value == '\x03')
                    {
                        reading = false;
                        if (msgBuilder.Length > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(msgBuilder);
                            msgBuilder.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value == '\x00')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (reading)
                    {
                        msgBuilder.Append(value);
                    }
                }

                Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            Connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Call causing the issue is located in **else** statement of **ExecuteAsync** method

```
else
{
    TcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 1234);
    HandleClient(TcpClient); // <-- Call causing the issue
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "After call");
}
```

The code reads properly from the socket, but it blocks initialization of WebServer and TcpServer. Actually, even **log** method is not being reached. No matter if I put **await** in front of **HandleClient()** or not, the code behaves the same.

I've done some tests, and I figured out that this piece of code is not blocking anymore ("After call" log shows up):

```
else
{
    TcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 1234);
    await Task.Delay(1);
    HandleClient(TcpClient); // <- moving Task.Delay into HandleClient also works
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "After call");
}
```

This also works like a charm (if I try to await Task.Run(), it will block "After call" log, but rest of app will start with no problem):

```
else
{
    tcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 6969);
    Connected = true;
    Task.Run(() => ReceiveAsync(tcpClient));
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "After call");
}
```

There is couple more combinations which make it work, but my question is– why other methods work (especially 1ms delay- this completely shut downs my brain) and firing HandleClient() without await doesn't? I know that fire and forget may not be the most elegant solution, but it should work and do it's job shouldn't it? I searched for almost a month, and still didn't find a single explanation for that. At this point I have hard time falling asleep at night, cause I have no one to ask and can't stop thinking about that..

## Update

(Sorry for disappearing for over a day without any answers)

After many many hours of investigation, I started debugging once again. Every time I would hit **while** loop in HandleClient(), I was losing control over debugger, program seemed to continue to work, but it would never reach **await streamReader.ReadAsync()**. At some point I decided to change condition in the while loop to **true** (I have no idea why I didn't think of trying it before), and everything began to work as expected. Messages would get read from tcp socket, and other services would fire up without any issues.

Here is piece of code causing issue

```
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) <----- issue
    {
        var res = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
        // ...
```

After that observation, I decided to print out the result of EndOfStream before reaching the loop, to see what happens

```
Console.WriteLine(streamReader.EndOfStream);
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var res = await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
        // ...
```

Now the exact same thing was happening, but before even reaching the loop!

### Explanation

Note:
I'm not senior programmer, especially when it comes to dealing with asynchronous TCP communication so I might be wrong here, but I will try to do my best.

**streamReader.EndOfStream** is not a regular field, it is a property, and it has logic inside it's getter.

This is how it looks like from the inside:

```
public bool EndOfStream
{
    get
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        CheckAsyncTaskInProgress();

        if (_charPos < _charLen)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // This may block on pipes!
        int numRead = ReadBuffer();
        return numRead == 0;
    }
}
```

EndOfStream getter is synchronous method. To detect whether stream has ended or not, it calls ReadBuffer(). Since there is no data in the buffer yet and stream hasn't ended, method hangs until there is some data to read. Unfortunately it cannot be used in asynchronous context, it will always block (unfortunately because it seems to be the only way to instantly detect interrupted connection, broken cable or end of stream).

I don't have finished piece of code yet, I need to rewrite it and add some broken connection detection. I will post my solution I soon as I finish.

I would like to thank everyone for trying to help me, and especially @RoarS. who took biggest part in discussion, and spent some of his own time to take a closer look at my issue.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` blocks. use await `Console.Out.WriteLineAsync` instead

Comment: also fire and forget is really a bad idea, since your task may take way more than 100ms and it will cause multiple calls of the same method over and over

Comment: You can easily connect the debugger and step-in to see at which line the code is waiting. If you share your finding it might be easier to debug your code

Comment: In addition to above arguments, you share `Connected` between async and non-async code. I solved something like this (endless loop/recursion) earlier today. Please have a look at the answer to question and see if that will give you some hints what to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549677/how-should-i-test-that-a-concurrent-queue-has-a-sliding-timescale-cap-on-items-t/63550072#63550072

Comment: @Bizhan 
1) Console.WriteLine doesn't change a thing, I can remove this line and code behaves in the same way.

2) Yeah, it can take more, I can move Connected = true right after tcpClient initialization, and it won't be called more than once, because only HandleClient method sets it to false, but it still doesn't explain this behavior.

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü I tried to, many times. Client connects, and as soon as I reach while(!streamReader.EndOfStream) loop, I loose control over debugger, it looks like code just continues to work, but services are not getting initialized (reading from this client works, but web api and tcp server doesn't respond)

Comment: Guys, I know that this code isn't perfect. It's just a little scratch to show what my issue is or maybe more like– where I lack knowledge? I only want to know why Task.Delay(1) makes everything async when fire and forget standalone blocks stuff. The rest of it, like eg. @RoarS. has spotted, still needs some work.

Comment: Task.Delay(1) will pause execution for 1 millisec, and when execution resumes, it most likely will happen on a different thread. And that is what async is about; giving back thread to pool while wating for something, and get a thread back when execution is ready to resume.

Comment: @RoarS. That's very probable but even if it works like that, then why standalone HandleClient() called without await doesn't let other code execute? Shouldn't it get moved to another thread automatically if it takes too much resources? What would be the best solution to do it "gracefully", Task.Run?

Comment: Personally, I would add the job to a queue and let other parts of the code process the queue. If you look at the link I sent you above, there is a solution for exactly that.

Comment: @RoarS. Your code looks nice, but I can't really see how it relates to my situation. I mean, piece of code that I have shown is supposed to serve as TcpClient. This is one connection and I just need to make it read asynchronously so other services can run alongside it without blocking. I'm utilizing .NET Core Hosted service for a reason (to have long-running tasks in the background without blocking each other and my WebApi). I just don't understand why this is blocking anything. Usually when you trigger task without await, any code that is below will execute instantly, but not in my case, why?

Comment: @RoarS. On the other hand I see possibility to use your code, maybe in my tcp server implementation, where I need to serve many clients at once (but this is stuff to do later, not necessary at this point, separate service, I need to take care of TcpClient first) or I could dispatch messages from TcpClient, cause some of them may be longer operations, but still, need to do async reading from client first..

Answer (score 0):

This is poorly documented behaviour of the `BackgroundService` class. All registered `IHostedService` will be started sequentially in the order they were registered. The application will not start until each `IHostedService` has returned from `StartAsync`. A `BackgroundService` is an `IHostedService` that starts your `ExecuteAsync` task before returning from `StartAsync`. Async methods will run until their first call to await an incomplete task before returning.

TLDR; If you don't await anything in your `ExecuteAsync` method, the server will never start.

Since you aren't awaiting that async method, your code boils down to;

```cs
while(true)
    HandleClient(...);
```

(Do you really want to spawn an infinite number of `TcpClient` as fast as the CPU will go?). There's a really easy fix;

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I dont't think the second case is what OP tries to do.  `Connected` is used as lock, hence to me the intention seems to keep a single instance of `TcpClient` busy.

Comment: In OP's example, `TcpClientService` was registered first, but will only await when Connected is true. Until then it will loop, creating new clients and attempting to connect them. I assume it's attempting to connect to the `TcpServerService` that was registered second. But if a `BackgroundService` never awaits, no further `IHostedService` will start....

Comment: I managed to find the issue guys, it was streamReader.EndOfStream which was blocking whole context, so no matter if I awaited HandleClient or not, I had the same result. You can find explanation in update part of my original question, thanks for your help, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote any of your answers :(